# I have FLV video and added a cue points using Media Encoder. when i seek to some cuepoint image wont change

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flvplayback

1. I added cue points in video (Navigation)
2. imported the FLV video in Flash and liked in FLVPlayback
3. Added "next" & "Previous" button and linked to the video (Instant Name for Next button is "nexT", Instant Name for Previous Button is "preV")

Next and previous button works fine. But when i movie the seek bar of the video it wont recognised.

EX : On Cuepoint 1, i want one image to load.
     On Cuepoint 2. i want another image to load.
same for Cuepoint 3 to Cuepoint 50.

When i slide the video to, the image wont changes.

Comment: From where you are getting images names, from the Cuepoints or an array  ... ?

Comment: I have one folder with images... I have added Loader component (Where images will load up on cue points). But the problem is with i move the seekbar, it wont recognised.